# SQL Calcluated Fields to Transform Rows of Data into Multiple Based on Column Values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Say I had lines of data that looked like this:

```
[Customer] - [$ spent of shirts] - [$ spent on pants] - [$ spent on shoes]
John - $10 - $20 - $15   
Maria - $20 - $10 - $50
```

But I wanted to transform the data to look like this:

```
[Customer] - [Product] - [Amount Spent] 
John - Shirts - $10 
John - Pants - $20 
John - Shoes - $15
Maria - Shirts - $20
Maria - Pants - $10
Maria - Shoes - $50
```

Is this possible? Is there calculated logic I can create for Product and Amount Spent using the top lines of data?

Thank you!

Comment: You are looking for Unpivoting table, seek here, there are tons of questions on it.

Comment: I removed the mysql tag, because the column headers suggest SQL Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like to do this using `cross apply`:

```
select v.*
from t cross apply
     (values ([Customer], 'Shirts', [$ spent of shirts]),
             ([Customer], 'Pants', [$ spent of pants]),
             ([Customer], 'Shoes', [$ spent of shoes])
     ) v(Customer, Product, AmountSpent);
```